# pl/sql procedure with savepoint

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a table employee with columns: id, name, department, salary. 
I want to create a procedure which increase salary for all employees in a specific department and run procedure  if salary is less than 500, otherwise return to savepoint.
I don't know how to write the exception

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `procedure1` (IN dep1 INT(11), IN sal1 INT(11))
BEGIN
   SAVEPOINT point1;
   UPDATE employee SET salary=salary+sal1
   WHERE department=dep1;
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN salary>500 THEN
   ROLLBACK TO point1;
 END
```

Comment: What do you mean, "run procedure?"  call another procedure instead of doing the update?  That is not an exception.  This isn't valid pl/sql.

Comment: i want to check if salary is less then 500 then make update

Comment: You have tagged the question with PL/SQL (Oracle), but the syntax you have shown seems to indicate MySQL (those dreaded backticks, int(11)) - so what are you using? Oracle or MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

maybe you need to review your point of view, because you can add another WHERE clause in order to update only those salaries who are less than or equal to 500, e.g.:

```
   UPDATE employee SET salary=salary+sal1
   WHERE department=dep1
     AND salary <= 500;
```

With this I think you don't need a SAVEPOINT, however find here how to use it:  [SAVEPOINT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#i7105)

Hope this help!!.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure1 (dep1 IN NUMBER,  sal1 IN NUMBER)
BEGIN

   UPDATE employee SET salary=salary+sal1
   WHERE department= dep1 and
         salary <= 500;
   COMMIT;
 END;
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `salary <= 500` ?